# Are apps downloaded from an unrestricted market disabled when the phone is used in a restricted market?

Tags: google-play-store

I am currently on t-mobile in the US and have access to a lot apps that are not available in the Indian android market. What happens to the apps that I download off the US market when I return to India and plug in my local sim card?

Comment: Anecdotally: I moved from T-Mobile to Rogers (Canada) and all my apps kept working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most applications should not disable itself, but that depends on the individual applications.

Comment: Something using market licensing checks would probably refuse to run

Comment: There are Market licensing checks?

Comment: @Matthew Read: Yes there is: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html but I'm not sure if the Market licensing check will check your current country by default.